# JustLee Database using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm obviously new here and in need of assistance. My problem is calculating the profit from the Books table. I would appreciate any help as our professor gave us this project at the last minute before the semester ending.

```
CREATE TABLE Books (
ISBN VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Title VARCHAR(30),
PubDate DATE,
PubID INT,
Cost DECIMAL(5, 2),
Retail DECIMAL(5, 2),
Discount DECIMAL(4, 2),
Category VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('1059831198','BODYBUILD IN 10 MINUTES A DAY','2005-01-05',4,18.75,30.95, NULL, 'FITNESS');
INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('0401140733','REVENGE OF MICKEY','2005-12-14',1,14.20,22.00, NULL, 'FAMILY LIFE');
INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('4981341710','BUILDING A CAR WITH TOOTHPICKS','2006-03-18',2,37.80,59.95, 3.00, 'CHILDREN');
INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('8843172113','DATABASE IMPLEMENTATION','2003-06-13',3,31.40,55.95, NULL, 'COMPUTER');
INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('3437212490','COOKING WITH MUSHROOMS','2004-02-28',4,12.50,19.95, NULL, 'COOKING');
INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('3957136468','HOLY GRAIL OF ORACLE','2005-12-31',3,47.25,75.95, 3.80, 'COMPUTER');
INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('1915762492','HANDCRANKED COMPUTERS','2005-01-21',3,21.80,25.00, NULL, 'COMPUTER');
INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('9959789321','E-BUSINESS THE EASY WAY','2006-03-21',2,37.90,54.50, NULL, 'COMPUTER');
INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('2491748320','PAINLESS CHILD-REARING','2004-07-14',5,48.00,89.95, 4.50, 'FAMILY LIFE');
INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('0299282519','THE WOK WAY TO COOK','2004-07-14',4,19.00,28.75, NULL, 'COOKING');
INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('8117949391','BIG BEAR AND LITTLE DOVE','2005-11-05',5,5.32,8.95, NULL, 'CHILDREN');
INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('0132149871','HOW TO GET FASTER PIZZA','2006-11-05',4,17.85,29.95, 1.50, 'SELF HELP');
INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('9247381001','HOW TO MANAGE THE MANAGER','2003-11-05',1,15.40,31.95, NULL, 'BUSINESS');
INSERT INTO BOOKS 
VALUES ('2147428890','SHORTEST POEMS','2005-05-01',5,21.85,39.95, NULL, 'LITERATURE');
```

Comment: If this question came at the end of a semester and the answer is not immediate, perhaps a quick review of your notes are in order. This is just simple math ... 

Comment: Honestly, we didn't cover the whole book and she hardly assigned assignments where we had to use arithmetic operators. My classmate came up with this:

SELECT Title, Retail * Discount
FROM Books
WHERE Retail * Discount = Cost;

But nothing appeared in the Result Grid. When I mentioned it to him, he brushed it off because we're honestly frustrated by now haha.

Comment: This sort of perspective will not get you very far in the real world. Middle managers are far  more vague and far less forgiving than educators. Start with the definition of "profit" and how it's calculated, then go from there. Everything you need is in the sample data that was provided.